# Starch recommendation based on research

Tags: sugar, carbohydrates, fda

I am trying to identify daily recommended/suggested values based on research. I understand the values differ for each person and therefore no absolutes can be drawn but I am trying to identify suggestions based on research.

I found wonderful articles for sugar;

- American Heart Association: [Sugar 101](https://www.heart.org/en/healthy-living/healthy-eating/eat-smart/sugar/sugar-101#.WIzyC1MrJaQ)
- American Heart Association: [Added Sugar](https://www.heart.org/en/healthy-living/healthy-eating/eat-smart/sugar/added-sugars)

An interesting discussion on stack exchange

- [Can one candy bar per day be part of a healthy diet?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/9935/can-one-candy-bar-per-day-be-part-of-a-healthy-diet/10978#10978)

Let me point out that these articles do not have references to scientific journals but I trust the recommended values because I tried a 2 week challenge and I saw a huge difference physically, emotionally and socially. It has been 2 months now and I have not stopped my 36g sugar limit.

My question is, just like sugar, too much of starch is not good for you but I am yet to find a recommendation for starch limits. I have noticed [300g of carbohydrate for a 2,000 calorie diet per day recommendation by FDA](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/InteractiveNutritionFactsLabel/factsheets/Total_Carbohydrate.pdf) but I would like to know just the starch recommendataion.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking for a government recommendation for daily starch intake?

Comment: https://www.livestrong.com/article/522357-how-to-calculate-starches-in-nutrition-labels/

Comment: @CareyGregory, not necessarily government but any organization which has invested in researching. Preferably one which does not have affiliations to the commercial food industry

Answer (score 2):

There are a wide variety of starch sources, from refined flours with a high [glycemic index](https://www.health.harvard.edu/healthy-eating/glycemic-index-and-glycemic-load-for-100-foods) (e.g. white crackers or bread) to whole grains and nuts with lower glycemic index, high fiber, and many other nutrients.  The body processes them differently even if they have ultimately the same # of calories or starches.

Therefore in the field of medicine, one of the predominant evidence-based approaches to carbohydrate intake is in terms of (1) quality and (2) proportion, rather than just an RDA of grams or # calories.

Harvard's SPH released an [evidence-based update](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/healthy-eating-plate-vs-usda-myplate/) to the [original USDA MyPlate](https://www.choosemyplate.gov/MyPlate) where whole grains are shown in the proportion recommended.  Note that proportion and qualities are what are highlighted rather than exact grams, calories, or measurements.

[image: Healthy Eating Plate]

Comment: I do not disagree with the answer. But: *I'd* say "severely limit refined grains" – & where do I read actual *starches* into that diagram? My main sources of starches are now various tubers, and on that it just says "potatoes don't count"

Comment: That's a good point, I usually add the disclaimer of limiting simple starches, as well as some other points.  Where would you recommend putting that in?